# transformar itens de uma lista em colunas separadas ou estender dataframe até o final

Tags: python, pandas

Tenho uma classe com um elemento que é uma lista estou tentando exibir em um dataframe do pandas essa lista em uma unica linha para representar o inventario do personagem.

atribuição dos itens na lista:

```
if self.wealth == "rich":
        self.inventory = ["dagger","nobles's clothing", "cloak","backpack","rations for a week","waterskin",
                          "potion of healing","pouch for coins","personal servant","personal guard", " three saddled horses"]
```

estou fazendo o dataframe dessa forma porem acaba cortando a lista por ser muito grande, gostaria de fazer de um jeito que não cortasse essa linha.

```
inventory = pd.DataFrame({"Inventory": [self.inventory]," ": " "})
inventory.set_index(" ", inplace=True)

display(inventory)
```

Answer (score 3):

Se você precisa unir os elementos da lista `inventory` em uma única `string` pode fazer desta forma:

```
inventory = ["dagger","nobles's clothing","cloak",
             "backpack","rations for a week","waterskin",
             "potion of healing","pouch for coins","personal servant",
             "personal guard", "three saddled horses"]

invent = ",".join(inventory)

print(f"Inventory: {invent}")
```

Saída:

```
Inventory: dagger,nobles's clothing,cloak,backpack,rations for a week,waterskin,potion of healing,pouch for coins,personal servant,personal guard,three saddled horses
```

Comment: acabei resolvendo de outra forma mas não sabia desse uso do join() obg pela info.

Comment: Que bom que você conseguiu @pydoni, abraço e até a próxima!

Answer (score 1):

acabei conseguindo resolver transformando cada item da lista em uma coluna própria desta forma

```
    idf = pd.DataFrame({"Inventory": [self.inventory]})
    idf = idf["Inventory"].apply(pd.Series)
    idc = pd.DataFrame({" ": ["Inventory"]})#usei isso para deixar como um index mais bonito
    idf = idf.rename(columns = lambda x : "item_" + str(x))
    inventory = pd.concat([idc[:],idf[:]], axis=1)
    inventory.set_index(" ", inplace=True)

    display(inventory)
```

Comment: Usar `apply(pd.Series)` pode custar muito tempo de processamento dependendo do tamanho dos dados que você esta trabalhando. Da uma olhada na minha resposta :)

Answer (score 1):

Uma alternativa melhor(mais rápida) seria criar um novo DataFrame convertendo a coluna **Inventory** para um array `numpy` com `value`, dessa forma:

```
df = pd.DataFrame(idf["Inventory"].values.tolist())
df.index = ['Inventory']
df.columns = ["item_" + str(x) for x in df.columns]
```

Usando a biblioteca `timeit`, é possível ver a diferença no tempo de execução

```
%%timeit

idf2 = idf["Inventory"].apply(pd.Series)
idc = pd.DataFrame({" ": ["Inventory"]})#usei isso para deixar como um index mais bonito
idf2 = idf2.rename(columns = lambda x : "item_" + str(x))
inventory = pd.concat([idc[:],idf2[:]], axis=1)
inventory.set_index(" ", inplace=True)
```

> 6.36 ms ± 149 µs per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 100 loops each)

```
%%timeit

df = pd.DataFrame(idf["Inventory"].values.tolist())
df.index = ['Inventory']
df.columns = ["item_" + str(x) for x in df.columns]
```

> 3.27 ms ± 88.3 µs per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 100 loops each)

Quase 2x mais rápido!